# how to downgrade flutter version?

Tags: flutter, dart, version

Im trying to downgrade to 3.0.5 with terminal and typed

```
git reset --hard e85ea0e79c6d894c120cda4ee8ee10fe6745e187
```

but error says

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

how can I solve??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop installing and uninstalling versions! Get yourself an install of package:fvm, aka https://pub.dev/packages/fvm, aka http://fvm.app.  You can have per-project selection of any flutter version that has been published, as well as keep the latest version as your global default.

Answer (score 6):

`flutter downgrade 3.0.5`

Change the version from `3.0.5` to as your wish

Run this command.